# is there any way to sync the folder in my mobile storage with the folder in my AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, amazon-cognito

i have a folder called 'AWS S3 Bucket' in my android mobile storage and another folder in AWS S3 bucket. Now i want these (the folder in my mobile storage and the S3 contents) to be in sync when the mobile is connected to internet. I want exactly the same process like Dropbox sync.

Currently i'm sending files from mobile device to a Handler (.Net) the Handler will send the files to my the SQL server, now i want to replace this process with AWS.
How can i achieve this? please help..

**Update:**

I want exactly the same what the "FolderSync Lite" app doing with Amazon S3.  [HERE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=en) is the link for the app.

Comment: How did you manage to achieve this? I need the same functionality. @AndroidManifester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS Android SDK doesn't have a S3 sync feature. The closest you can get is to use TransferManager.downloadDirectory() and uploadDirectory(), but unfortunately it's lack of synchronization perspective.

Comment: thanks for the info. can you suggest me is there anyway i can have synchronization feature in my android app?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found out that it is not possible to have syncing between mobile folder and S3 bucket folder..!

Comment: Did you find any other work around or a totally different service that could make this kind of use case easier?